# Using an ordered dict as object dictionary in python

Tags: python, ordereddictionary

I don't know why this doesn't work:

I'm using the [odict](http://dev.pocoo.org/hg/sandbox/raw-file/tip/odict.py) class from [PEP 372](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0372/), but I want to use it as a `__dict__` member, i.e.:

```
class Bag(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = odict()
```

But for some reason I'm getting weird results. This works:

```
>>> b = Bag()
>>> b.apple = 1
>>> b.apple
1
>>> b.banana = 2
>>> b.banana
2
```

But trying to access the actual dictionary doesn't work:

```
>>> b.__dict__.items()
[]
>>> b.__dict__
odict.odict([])
```

And it gets weirder:

```
>>> b.__dict__['tomato'] = 3
>>> b.tomato
3
>>> b.__dict__
odict.odict([('tomato', 3)])
```

I'm feeling very stupid. Can you help me out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The closest answer to your question that I can find is at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2006-April/033155.html.

Basically, if `__dict__` is not an actual `dict()`, then it is ignored, and attribute lookup fails.

The alternative for this is to use the odict as a member, and override the getitem and setitem methods accordingly.

```
>>> class A(object) :
...     def __init__(self) :
...             self.__dict__['_odict'] = odict()
...     def __getattr__(self, value) :
...             return self.__dict__['_odict'][value]
...     def __setattr__(self, key, value) :
...             self.__dict__['_odict'][key] = value
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a
<__main__.A object at 0xb7bce34c>
>>> a.x = 1
>>> a.x
1
>>> a.y = 2
>>> a.y
2
>>> a.odict
odict.odict([('x', 1), ('y', 2)])
```

Comment: Wow, didn't expect it to be an actual python bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Everything in sykora's answer is correct.  Here's an updated solution with the following improvements:

1. works even in the special case of accessing `a.__dict__` directly
2. supports `copy.copy()`
3. supports the `==` and `!=` operators
4. uses [`collections.OrderedDict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) from Python 2.7.

...

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class OrderedNamespace(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(OrderedNamespace, self).__setattr__( '_odict', OrderedDict() )

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        odict = super(OrderedNamespace, self).__getattribute__('_odict')
        if key in odict:
            return odict[key]
        return super(OrderedNamespace, self).__getattribute__(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, val):
        self._odict[key] = val

    @property
    def __dict__(self):
        return self._odict

    def __setstate__(self, state): # Support copy.copy
        super(OrderedNamespace, self).__setattr__( '_odict', OrderedDict() )
        self._odict.update( state )

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__

    def __ne__(self, other):
        return not self.__eq__(other)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a library with attribute access to OrderedDict, the [orderedattrdict](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/orderedattrdict) package provides this.

```
>>> from orderedattrdict import AttrDict
>>> conf = AttrDict()
>>> conf['z'] = 1
>>> assert conf.z == 1
>>> conf.y = 2
>>> assert conf['y'] == 2
>>> conf.x = 3
>>> assert conf.keys() == ['z', 'y', 'x']
```

Disclosure: I authored this library. Thought it might help future searchers.