# What's an elegant way to create a dictionary from another dictionary's keys and an array of values?

Tags: python, dictionary

How can I create another dictionary using the keys of another dictionary, and an array of values?

I thought about doing this:

```
zipped = zip(theExistingDict.keys(), arrayOfValues)
myNewDict = dict(zipped)
```

However, this doesn't quite work, each value from `arrayOfValues` are paired with an arbitrary key in the resulting dictionary. I don't have any control over which element from `arrayOfValues` is paired with which key in `theExistingDict.keys()`.

`theExistingDict` looks like this:

`{u'actual bitrate': 4, u'Suggested Bitrate': 3, u'title': 2, u'id': 1, u'game slot': 0}`

`arrayOfValues` looks like this:

`1.0, u'GOLD_Spider Solitaire', u'Spider\\nSolitaire', 120000.0, 120000.0`

So: I would like `arrayOfValues[0]` to map to `game slot` (because in the dictionary it has value 0).

Is there an easy and elegant way to do this?

Comment: well, which order do you want to have? and what is the connection between keys and values, then?

Comment: `theExistingDict.keys()` will give you the keys in arbitrary order. You probably have to sort it somehow. Only you know which key-value pairs belong together.

Comment: @SilentGhost - please see my edits above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your existing dictionary itself contains information on the positions of the elements in the list: you could do:

```
>>> exist = {u'title': 2, u'actual bitrate': 4, u'id': 1, u'game slot': 0, u'Suggested Bitrate': 3}
>>> l = [1.0, u'GOLD_Spider Solitaire', u'Spider\\nSolitaire', 120000.0, 120000.0]
>>> dict((k, l[v]) for k, v in exist.iteritems())
{u'Suggested Bitrate': 120000.0, u'game slot': 1.0, u'actual bitrate': 120000.0, u'id': u'GOLD_Spider Solitaire', u'title': u'Spider\\nSolitaire'}
```

or in py3k/python 2.7+:

```
>>> {k: l[v] for k, v in exist.items()}
{'Suggested Bitrate': 120000.0, 'game slot': 1.0, 'actual bitrate': 120000.0, 'id': 'GOLD_Spider Solitaire', 'title': 'Spider\\nSolitaire'}
```

Comment: Very elegant - this is the kind of solution I was looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, a Dictionary doesn't have any order defined in it.  The python docs say, "Keys and values are listed in an arbitrary order which is non-random, varies across Python implementations, and depends on the dictionary’s history of insertions and deletions."

If you're looking to use the original order that you added the items into the dictionary, you can try looking for an alternative implementation of dictionary that preserves this order -- e.g. http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/odict.html

Answer (score 0):

In light of the comments above, it's possible that a dictionary for `theExistingDict` may not be the structure you are looking for.

You may be interested in an [ordered dictionary](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/107747-ordered-dictionary/).

See also the answers to ["What’s the way to keep the dictionary parameter order in Python?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302663/whats-the-way-to-keep-the-dictionary-parameter-order-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

perhaps something more like:

```
from operator import itemgetter
zip( array_of_values, [ a for a, _ in sorted(existing_dict.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1)) ] )
```

it can be modified further if you'd like to match index with integer, possibly with unused values...

```
 zipped = [ (k, a) for i, a in enumerate(array_of_values) for k, v in existing_dict.iteritems() if i == v ]
 new_dict = dict(zipped)
```